# How to unit test an empty enum?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, enums, nunit

I have an extension method that calculates due date based on date period type. The method looks like this:

```
public static DateTime CalculateDueDate(this DateTime date, OffsetType offsetType, int offset)
{
    switch (offsetType)
    {
        case OffsetType.Days:
            return date.AddDays(offset);
        case OffsetType.Weeks:
            return date.AddWeeks(offset);
        case OffsetType.Months:
            return date.AddMonths(offset);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offsetType", offsetType, null);
    }
}
```

where OffsetType enum has these possible values:

```
public enum OffsetType
{
    Months = 1,
    Weeks = 2,
    Days = 3
}
```

How can I make sure that **`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`** is thrown when `OffsetType` `enum` is not provided (or provided with invalid value)? Do I even need to worry about unit testing that exception if `OffsetType` parameter is not `null`?

**UPDATE:**

I wish I could vote for multiple answers. I decided to use out-of-range value suggested by [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37972480/4383585) and [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37972451/4383585). Here is my fins unit test:

```
    [Test]
    public void CalculateDueDate_Throw_Exception_Test()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        var period = 3;
        var offsetType = (OffsetType) (-1);

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => date.CalculateDueDate(offsetType, period));
    }
```

Comment: enums can't be null, they are value types

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just cast an out-of-range value to the enum type:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => {
    CalculateDueDate(date, (OffsetType)(-1), offset);
});
```

Which values you can use depend on the underlying type of the enum.

Answer (score 7):

You can construct an illegal value by explicitly casting an out-of-range `int` to `OffsetType`, for example

```
OffsetType t = (OffsetType)5;
```

Now you can call `CalculateDueDate`, pass it the illegal value constructed for the unit test, and assert that an exception of type `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown.

**Note:** Although it is redundant in situations when you perform an exhaustive `switch` covering all `enum` cases, in situations when you cover *some* valid cases with a `default` branch you should check for invalid values using [`Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OffsetType), t)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether a value is valid for a specific enum with [Enum.IsDefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx), eg:

```
if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OffsetType),offsetType))
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offsetType", offsetType, null);
}
```

Enums are value types so they can't be null.